# When deriving a encryption/decryption key from a passphrase, what encoding is the most commonly used?

Tags: encryption, unicode, hash, cryptography

When I'm deriving an encryption key from a passphrase, it is quite common to use a hash algorithm to derive the key from the passphrase. Examples are SHA-256 (single or multiple rounds) and SCrypt.

But, when entering the passphrase in the hash function, is it usually encoded using UTF-8 or UTF-16?

I know it's impossible to be "compliant" with all other existing encryption mechanisms, but I'd like to know what way is in fact the most common.

Comment: When in doubt, UTF-8. :)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Stupid question, should probably delete it :p

Comment: UTF-8 is the unofficial default for PBKDF2, but it is only a hint in the specifications. Microsoft will default to it, Java will use the lower 8 bits of the Unicode code point (mainly so you can use an erasable `char[]` as input). For western countries, you may op to only allow ASCII, it's likely to be most compatible across implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the entropy is the same, the choice between UTF8 and UTF16 really doesn't matter.

Comment: I was thinking if people wanted to manually decrypt data recovered from the service I'm providing, it can be useful to follow industry standards so that they don't have to do unconventional things.
But I already noticed that UTF-8 was standardised in the case I was looking at. (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0038.mediawiki)